# Jobs scheduling in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to create Jobs scheduling. 
I used this command :  python manage.py create_jobs app_name
but I get : Unknown command: 'create_jobs'

Comment: Django has no `create_jobs` command. The package [`django-extensions`](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jobs_scheduling.html) can offer that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has *no* `create_jobs` command. A package named [**`django-extensions`** <sup>[readthedocs]</sup>](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest) has such command.

You can install it by installing `django-extensions` in your virtual environment, for example with:

```
pip3 install django-extensions
```

and in the [**`INSTALLED_APPS`** setting <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#installed-apps) of the `settings.py` file, add `'django_extensions'`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # …
    'django_extensions',
    # …
]
```

Then you can indeed use the [**`create_jobs`** command](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jobs_scheduling.html).